# Unable to install React using npm install and dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see request/request#3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@3.0.2: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.0.3: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.5: please switch to a stable version
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the
```

When installing React using command line showing above errors, what to do?

Comment: Those are all warnings, not errors.  But what specific command did you use to try installing react? Are you trying to install an old version?  (I'm seeing left-pad in there which has been deprecated for ages; a current `npm install react` would not give those warnings afaik)

Comment: Just used npm install because dependencies already mentioned in package.json

Comment: OK, you're not trying to install React then, you're trying to install a react-based project containing some deprecated packages. Try `npm update` and `npm outdated` for a start, but you may end up having to update some modules manually.

Comment: thanks, there may be other issue because of that it didn't work. Now it is properly working.

Answer (score -1):

those are not errors, some warnings you can skip

Comment: But because of that npm start not working

Comment: *But because of that npm start not working* - not likely. These **warnings** did not prevent anything from installing. Your problem is likely elseware. Instead, please provide details around what *npm start not working* means. Did it produce an error then?

Comment: thanks, there may be other issue because of that it didn't work.Now it is properly working.